# iOS Swift 3 - delete contact information field Anniversary

Tags: swift, contacts

Is it possible in Swift 3 to mass delete the Anniversary field in a specific selection of contacts?

I found code to add Anniversary info to a contact, but I'm looking for the code to delete existing Anniversary info from specific contacts.

Sample to add:

```
//add anniversary
let anniversaryDate = NSDateComponents()
anniversaryDate.month = 6
anniversaryDate.day = 13
let anniversary = CNLabeledValue(label: "Anniversary",
  value: anniversaryDate)
fooBar.dates = [anniversary]

//save
let request = CNSaveRequest()
request.addContact(fooBar, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
do{
  try storeo.executeSaveRequest(request)
  print("Successfully stored the contact")
} catch let err{
  print("Failed to save the contact. \(err)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the dates and then update the contact.

```
let mutableContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

let dates = mutableContact.dates.filter({ $0.label != "Anniversary" })

mutableContact.dates = dates

let request = CNSaveRequest()
request.updateContact(mutableContact)

do {

    try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(request)

} catch let error {

    print("Failed to updated contact. \(error)")
}
```